# I'm trying to write a simple IRC bot but I'm getting null exception why is that?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code for `Form1`:

```
namespace Irc_Bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int port;
        string buf, nick, owner, server, chan;
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient sock = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        System.IO.TextReader input;
        System.IO.TextWriter output;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Get nick, owner, server, port, and channel from user
            label1.Text = "Enter bot nick: ";
            nick = textBox1.Text;
            label2.Text = "Enter bot owner name: ";
            owner = textBox2.Text;
            label3.Text = "Enter server name: ";
            label4.Text = "Enter port number: ";
            if (textBox4.Text != "")
            port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            label5.Text = "Channel: ";
            chan = textBox5.Text;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void connectToIrc()
        {
            //Connect to irc server and get input and output text streams from TcpClient.
            server = textBox3.Text;
            port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            sock.Connect("chat.eu.freenode.net", port);//server, port);

            if (!sock.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!");
                return;
            }

            input = new System.IO.StreamReader(sock.GetStream());
            output = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sock.GetStream());

             //Starting USER and NICK login commands 
         output.Write(
            "USER " + nick + " 0 * :" + owner + "\r\n" +
            "NICK " + nick + "\r\n"
         );

         output.Flush();

         //Process each line received from irc server
         for (buf = input.ReadLine(); ; buf = input.ReadLine())
         {
             //Display received irc message
             Console.WriteLine(buf);

             //Send pong reply to any ping messages
             if (buf.StartsWith("PING ")) { output.Write(buf.Replace("PING", "PONG") + "\r\n"); output.Flush(); }
             if (buf[0] != ':') continue;

             /* IRC commands come in one of these formats:
              * :NICK!USER@HOST COMMAND ARGS ... :DATA\r\n
              * :SERVER COMAND ARGS ... :DATA\r\n
              */

             //After server sends 001 command, we can set mode to bot and join a channel
             if (buf.Split(' ')[1] == "001")
             {
                 output.Write(
                    "MODE " + nick + " +B\r\n" +
                    "JOIN " + chan + "\r\n"
                 );
                 output.Flush();
             }
         }
       }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connectToIrc();
        }
    }
}
```

For example I enter `chat.eu.freenode.net` for the server name and 6667 for the port.

And it's working if I'm entering this server through the MIRC program.

But in my program after 3-4 iterations in the `FOR` loop I'm getting exception null on this line:

```
if (buf.StartsWith("PING "))
```

The variable `buf` is `null`.

First it's doing the iterations some times then after 3-5 times its doing the command: `continue;` and then hang on for almost 15 seconds then its jumping to the line:

```
if (buf.StartsWith("PING "))
```

and throw the exception null message.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=Irc Bot

How can solve it ?

Comment: You are reading the stream `twice` each iteration except the first iteration. Why is that?

Comment: You right its not my code so i didnt check it. Is that the problem ? sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of the code is probably what's causing the error.

```
for (buf = input.ReadLine(); ; buf = input.ReadLine())
```

If there's only one line being sent then the first ReadLine takes that line and the second one gets null, resulting in buf being null if only one line is being sent.

Remove one of the `buf = input.ReadLine()` and also add a check that `buf != null` before you start to process it. That could look something like this. Notice that you have a `buf = input.ReadLine();` both before, and at the end of, the while loop. I've also added an ERROR check in the middle because I encountered an infinite loop on `if (buf[0] != ':') continue;` when I was testing with some invalid parameters.

```
//Process each line received from irc server
buf = input.ReadLine();
while (buf != null)
{

  //Display received irc message
  Console.WriteLine(buf);

  if (buf.StartsWith("ERROR")) break;

  //Send pong reply to any ping messages
  if (buf.StartsWith("PING ")) { output.Write(buf.Replace("PING", "PONG") + "\r\n"); output.Flush(); }
  if (buf[0] != ':') continue;

  //After server sends 001 command, we can set mode to bot and join a channel
  if (buf.Split(' ')[1] == "001")
  {
    output.Write(
      "MODE " + nick + " +B\r\n" +
      "JOIN " + chan + "\r\n"
    );
    output.Flush();
  }
  buf = input.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Ohlin i edited my question please look at it. Im still getting null on the buf variable even after removing one of the ReadLine() And where to check if its null or not ?

Comment: I've re-written the loop and tested it myself. Try with my new example.